# Calling a function in JavaScript beforeunload event on every browser without showing the Prompt

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, firefox, onbeforeunload

I need to call a function `finsihTheTest()` whenever user leaves a page by any mean like refresh, tab close or browser close. I tried using `beforeunload` event but it shows a prompt and as the prompt is being displayed the function is called and test is saved. I want to it call the function on user selection like if user decides to leaves the page only then the event should be called. If this is not possible i dont want a prompt as it is useless because the test is saved and user gets redirected without any interaction with the prompt. I am currently using following code:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
            finishTheTest();
            return 'Your data will be lost if you leave now. Are you sure?';
};
```

I have tried onbeforeunload and unload but was not successfull. I just need to save the student's test progress and mark it attempted whenever he leaves the page as the test is one time only and i need this function to be called at any cost.

**I need a the solution that does any of the following:**

1. Lets user interact with the prompt and only finishes the test when user clicks leaves the page.
2. Quietly calls the function `finishTheTest()` without showing any prompt and saves test progress.

Comment: I think you should just comment out the `return ...` which in some cases is being shown in the popup, or try with `return null`

Comment: Consider using the [`Beacon` API](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Beacon_API).

Comment: @Pieterjan when I comment this line the event does not fire at all on firefox.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Can you please explain how I can use beacon API for my task as I haven't worked with it before? I'll really appreciate that.

Comment: This is an X/Y problem - save the work regularly and the user can leave without being told.

Comment: *I tried using `beforeunload` event but it shows a prompt and as the prompt is being displayed the function is called* - how are you handling the prompt? Is it the regular `if(confirm(....)) { // user wants to leave } else { // user wants to stay }`, or something else? What happens if the user ignores the prompt, and simply closes the tab? What if they're on mobile, and dismiss the browser from the active apps view?

Comment: @UmerKhan I also haven’t worked with the Beacon API, but doesn’t the documentation I linked explain how to use it in detail?

Comment: @Umer Khan Yes in the link posted by @Sebastian Simon, under "Interfaces" you can see the [following link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/sendBeacon) which shows several code snippets. You just have to implement a `POST` request in your backend too

Comment: @SebastianSimon I went through the docs and yes it has a detailed explanation. I am using that. :)